# Have a list somewhere of features changed or implemented

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

For example, in [If you just witnessed tactical downvoting, is it a reportable offense?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046) Jeff announces that the window for reverting a downvote has been reduced. Larger features will make it to a blog entry but a lot of things like this won't.

Think of it as "living release notes". All it would be is a list of changes by date with short descriptions with links to a short description of the change, possibly with a link to something back here (if relevant) and/or the SO blog (again, if relevant).

It'd be nice to keep track of what's changed (and why).

Comment: Man, you know how much work that's going to be for me? :)  But it's a good idea; visibility/transparency is always welcome!

Comment: It doesn't have to be a lot of info imho. Jeff's 4 sentences about the tactical downvoting I think is more than sufficient as a description for "Reduced the window where you can undo votes".

Comment: A changelog of even the minor updates would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

How about [`[status-completed]+-[retag-request]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+-retag-request) ;-p

Comment: I am going to try say this in the nicest possible way but.... I HATE YOU :)

Comment: I hate me too...

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with this.

I often find myself confused when the site is **acting** different then expected, and unless I read every Meta entry, quickly get lost in the changes. I am extremely impressed at the way and rate Jeff and company implement changes, however even a **one liner**, similiar to the Virtual Box **release notes** [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) would be **extremely useful**.

It can even be a **locked community wiki question** on Meta that keeps getting update by the team.