# In a bounty scenario, can an answer from before the bounty be automatically accepted?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have a question regarding a scenario I could not understand from the FAQ. The scenario:

1. I asked a question
2. I received several answers, some of them received upvotes (e.g. one of them has 3 upvotes)
3. None of the answers helps me, even the upvoted ones
4. I start a bounty
5. For 7 days, no ones provides an answer or upvotes existing answers
6. Bounty period is finished

In that case, will the most upvoted question from before the bounty period be automatically accepted and receive half the bounty? If that's the case, it kind of misses the whole point of the bounty (receive other answers), isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It is not possible for an answer prior to the bounty start to be auto-accepted**.

The assumption is that the bounty owner was not satisfied with any of the existing answers at the time the bounty was started.

Comment: Thanks, so what does happen in this case?

Comment: Is this a recent rule? because on the 12th of July, my answer, made before the bounty, got auto-selected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056912/source-control-vs-revision-control

Comment: it was a change to the rules a few months ago. I'd have to go back through the SVN checkins to determine when it was added. In the case where no answer is "good enough" then nothing happens. However, if the owner does not accept in the alloted time, then no answer can ever be accepted.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for this comment. Side-note: this could be an argument in favor of a "release note" ;) ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18355/have-a-list-somewhere-of-features-changed-or-implemented )

Comment: Note: if you edit -- *during* a bounty -- an answer made *before* the bounty... it can also be auto-selected. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240018/1240054#1240054 . Is that coherent with your new rule?

Comment: Thanks, Jeff.  I'd also had an answer that I had given before a bounty was placed win the bounty.  This must have happened before the rule change.

Comment: If the OP's satisfaction mattered, they should be able to keep the question "unresolved" and not accept any answer.