# Badges and Bounties

Tags: support, badges, bounties

> You've earned the "Enthusiast" badge.
>   See your profile.

That's what just popped up at SO, I went to see my profile and I don't have the Enthusiast badge so I went to the badges page to see what it was about and Enthusiast is also not there, what is going on?

Also in the other day [I answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307738/dynamically-generating-a-word-cloud/1334235#1334235) which was supposed to be a bounty question (200 or 250 points if I remember correctly), the 7 day period has passed, I didn't won the bounty and no one else seems to have won it either and the question doesn't even appear at the featured page anymore.

Am I missing something? Is this the expected behavior of SO or is something not working right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Enthusiast badge, this blog post from Jeff should explain it: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/

For your bounty question, the following post may explain it: [In a bounty scenario, can an answer from before the bounty be automatically accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/in-a-bounty-scenario-can-an-answer-from-before-the-bounty-be-automatically-accep)

Answer (score 1):

Hell yeah you did. It's the [woot! badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/71/woot-enthusiast).

Welcome to the addict's world! Only a couple more days and I get me my Fanatic badge!

And bounties without any +2 answer just go away unto the ether, and the rep gets put back into the kitty to be doled out another day.

Comment: When was the tracking for Fanatic first implemented? I should have one coming too. :)

Comment: Lol, nice it would be more straightforward if SO just popped up "You've earned the "woot!" badge." lol. And about the bounty, how was that possible?

Comment: Same day Enthusiast hit. I think Jonathan did the math and it's 9/2 or 9/3...so possibly the next run it makes. Unless Jeff et al forgot to flip the switch to award it.

Comment: The Fanatic badge uses the same data that Enthusiast (WOOT!) uses; Stack Overflow's first are coming up in a couple of days :)

Answer (score 1):

> Also in the other day I answered this question which was supposed to be a bounty question (200 or 250 points if I remember correctly), the 7 day period has passed, I didn't won the bounty and no one else seems to have won it either and the question doesn't even appear at the featured page anymore.

For the Bounty, an answer needs to be accepted by the end of the bounty period or the highest voted answer will be auto-accepted, as long as it has 2 or more upvotes.  None of the ansnwers on the post to which you refer met the second criteria to trigger an auto-accept.