# Can a community wiki answer win the bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, community-wiki

In a cruel twist, the person with the [leading answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227950/programatic-accent-reduction-in-javascript-aka-text-normalization-or-unaccenting/228006#228006) for [my bountied question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227950/programatic-accent-reduction-in-javascript-aka-text-normalization-or-unaccenting) has turned his post into a community wiki answer by editing it a lot.  Is he still going to win the reputation for the bounty?

Also, it's not actually a substantially new answer. Had I liked it 11 months ago, I wouldn't have started a bounty now. Seeing as everyone who's looked at my question essentially either has no other answer or believes that this answer is the best way to do it, I'm willing to have him claim the bounty. I believe it should be awarded automatically given that he has four up votes and is the top voted of two answers. Am I right on that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [The bounty does not care whether the question is CW or not and will be awarded if it meets the rules.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/does-bounty-apply-to-a-cw-question/6805#6805)

Which means that the answer is up to scalping that bounty.

But...

> [It is not possible for an answer prior to the bounty start to be auto-accepted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/in-a-bounty-scenario-can-an-answer-from-before-the-bounty-be-automatically-accep/19005#19005)

Though not sure if that excludes any edits after the start of the bounty call.

Comment: I'm guessing it does actually.

Comment: I think a subsequent bounty could be added if it turns out that the CW answer isn't good enough, and more attention to the question is desired. Then the CW will no longer scalp the (subsequent) bounty.