# What are all the ways to gain/lose rep if all your posts are CW?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm considering a hair-brained scheme to lock my meta reputation at 4096 by turning all my existing and future posts into CW once I've achieved my goal.

But there are a few ways that my rep may still be affected.  I know that not everything is completely documented in any one place (for instance, the rep you lose if your question is flagged offensive by too many users).  Further I haven't participated as much over last summer and spring, and I believe the rep system has changed somewhat during that time.

For instance, do you still get rep if someone selects your answer, even if you've CW'd your answer (does it make a difference if the question is CW or not?)

If you CW an existing rep-earning answer, and a rep recalc is performed, does it take into account the date you CW'd your answer, or do you lose rep gained prior to CW?

There are probably many other ways to gain and lose rep even if everything is CW - what are some you can think of?

Comment: On a side note, if a moderator just happens to see this and is willing to perform a rep recalc on meta and SO, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Flag one of your posts for moderator attention and ask for a recalc that way.

Comment: If I'm lucky I'll lose over 3k on SO and get close to achieving 25,600 rep due to all the migrated questions and answers...

Comment: @Sinan - good call.

Comment: OK, just recalced your Meta rep. You went from 4052 to 4040.

Comment: Thanks.  Surprising that I lost so little...

Comment: Lost 862 on SO.  With all the highly rated subjective posts that got migrated I honestly expected it to be more.  Ah well.  I'll just have to hit 32,768 and hold it there.  Although this could all be for naught when the great downvote change and subsequent recalc happen...

Comment: well this obviously didn't stick...

Comment: @~quack - Pretty much, yeah.

Comment: So what's the deal with the overnight 550-point bounty? This is the first time I've won a bounty, but it might have been more fun if I'd known it was active. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downvoting is an obvious one (although you apparently never downvote).

---

Since this seems to have been permanently accepted thanks to the bounty, I'll make it a complete list.

#### Ways your reputation *can* change

- Cast a downvote on a non-wiki post: -1
- Remove a downvote on a post that was non-wiki when you voted: +1
- Have a post deleted as spam or offensive: -100
- Win a bounty: +*bounty*
- Reputation is recalculated after a post that you have earned reputation for is deleted: -*amount*
- Old upvotes on your posts are removed (possibly by the voting-anomalies process): -10 each

  #### Ways your reputation *cannot* change
- A vote (up or down) is cast on one of your posts
- Your answer is accepted
- You accept someone's answer

#### Reference:

- [How does reputation work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

---

A thought has struck me (impact severe, but not fatal): What happens if a vote is cast on a non-wiki post and later removed after the post is wikied? Is the reputation removed (if it was an upvote) or refunded to both parties (if it was a downvote), or is it permanent?

Comment: Just call me pollyanna.

Comment: If you insist... pollyanna.

Comment: Forgot about the rep recalc on other's deleted posts...

Answer (score 3):

If any of your questions or answers are flagged as offensive six times, you'll receive a -100 rep penalty.

Answer (score 1):

The only other way I think your rep can be affected is if you answer a question after a bounty has been set. [Then Community Wiki doesn't matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20931/can-a-community-wiki-answer-win-the-bounty)

(Although Jeff specifically says the bounty doesn't care about the *question* being CW, it seems the same logic applies to answers).

Answer (score 0):

If you set all of your posts to CW, and you get a rep re-calc, you will lose almost all of your rep.

If you do this **anybody** can force a rep re-calc on you by triggering the suspicious voting system. They could up-vote or down-vote several of your posts, in a row. The suspicious voting system will then, cancel all of the affected votes, and force a rep re-calc on you.

---

I don't really see any way to reliably maintain a given reputation level.
So I would recommend **not** trying to maintain a given reputation. Instead, just worry about giving good answers, and asking good questions.

Comment: I think the date of CW-ing is maintained, so I don't think that would result in retroactively losing reputation.

Comment: hrm.  So no clear answer on this then?