# Excluding down votes, what are the situations where you can lose rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow)

I've seen a couple of mentions on meta of a 100 rep point penalty if your question is closed for particular reasons ([here is one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/what-are-all-the-ways-to-gain-lose-rep-if-all-your-posts-are-cw/31875#31875)).  I've checked [the official FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq) but I can't see this mentioned anywhere.

Can somebody explain the definitive set of cases that can result in a 100 point rep loss penalty?

Once it is clarified I suggest maybe updating [this particular FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stackoverflow-how-do-they-work).

Comment: dupe : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Make it an answer then I will accept it!

Comment: @Dan J: that would be abusing the system for cheap rep.

Comment: @Æther: Not if the new question/answer links to the duplicate questions and has different terminology that makes it easier to find. It wasn't that easy to find as I spend 10 minutes looking for it and couldn't find it!