# Allow lapsed bounty questions to be accepted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why an answer can’t be accepted after an unresolved bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty)

From the comments on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19005) I understand that if no answer is accepted, the questioner cannot later accept any answer.

> [...] However, if the owner does not accept in the alloted time, then no answer can ever be accepted.

Would it be sensible to allow the answer to be accepted (with or without the answer receiving the bounty) after the bounty period has expired? If not what is the rationale?

I answered a [bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469786/generate-ant-build-file) this morning, about 8 hours before the deadline. The questioner hasn't been seen since raising the bounty so probably hasn't seen my answer. I believe my answer addresses their issue (well I would wouldn't I), but as it stands they would not now be able to accept it (assuming my answer meets their needs), as the bounty period passed and no answer had 2 upvotes.

If I'd seen the question earlier I may have ended up with a bounty, so there's a lesson for me somewhere. but I think that it should still be possible to accept a correct answer after a bounty has lapsed.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the referenced question was asking why an answer can't be accepted after the bounty period, I am asking if that policy can be changed.