# Why some random answer was auto accepted ? Is it possible to revert this?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I put up a bounty of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070375/what-are-you-the-most-excited-about-in-the-new-versions-of-jquery).

The answer automatically accepted was [some random one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070375/what-are-you-the-most-excited-about-in-the-new-versions-of-jquery/2115192#2115192) and not [the most upvoted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070375/what-are-you-the-most-excited-about-in-the-new-versions-of-jquery/2070386#2070386). Why so? Is this a bug or am I not getting how the bounty system works ? Is it possible to change this to accept the one that had the more upvotes and not some random one ?

Comment: See Jeff's answer to this question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/in-a-bounty-scenario-can-an-answer-from-before-the-bounty-be-automatically-accep

Comment: An imposter is among us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Jeff pointed out in the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/in-a-bounty-scenario-can-an-answer-from-before-the-bounty-be-automatically-accep) given by ChrisF, bounty will not be awarded to a question existing prior to the bounty.

If you want to award it to the most upvoted answer, **you should accept it yourself**, before the bounty runs out of time.

Comment: Also, allowing the system to pick the highest-voted answer instead of doing it yourself robs that person of half the bounty. If there *is* no good answer, this is fine, but it's definitely bad practice when there is a correct answer.

Comment: @mmyers: this was an open question, so the best suited answer would be, in that case, the one with the most upvotes