# What happened to my question bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, specific-question

I set a bounty of 500 for answer to my question, nothing happened no accepted answer, although I didn't get the right answer the people who tried to answer should get the reputation or I should get it back, here is the question:

> [Jboss Messaging JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478729/jboss-messaging-jms)

Answer (score 5):

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> ### What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?
>
> Once a bounty is started, the question
>   owner is obligated to select an
>   answer. If the owner does not choose
>   one, **auto-accept may be activated**
>   if:
>
> - answer has been posted AFTER the bounty started
> - *and* answer has at least 2 upvotes
>
> If the bounty expires without an
>   accepted answer, **[no answer can ever
>   be accepted for that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty/1414#1414)**.
>
> ### What is Auto-Accepting?
>
> If after one week no answer is
>   accepted by the original poster, then
>   the *new* answers with at least **+2**
>   upvotes posted **after** the bounty
>   start are considered eligible for
>   auto-accepting. The one with the most
>   upvotes (or in the case of a tie, the
>   earliest) will be automatically
>   accepted and awarded half of the
>   bounty.
>
> If no new answer has reached at least
>   **+2** votes, the bounty is forfeit.
>
> See also: [In a bounty scenario, can
>   an answer from before the bounty be
>   automatically
>   accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/in-a-bounty-scenario-can-an-answer-from-before-the-bounty-be-automatically).

Comment: @tretje `If the owner does not choose one, auto-accept may be activated if: answer have at least 2 upvotes` one answer has 3 upvotes

Comment: @Gandalf: That only counts for answers added *after* the bounty has been started.

Comment: @fretje well I'm not sure about that .. dammit at least 500 points could go to someone instead dropping to nowhere and I still didn't get my answer .. this rule is really lame .. thank you for your swift response

Comment: @Gandalf: It's a shame indeed... Make sure next time you accept an answer yourself, *before* the bounty expires. ;-)

Comment: @fretje well I have other obligations in life :D computer is about 9-10h per day .. other are spend outdoors or in bed so you can't make it everywhere, just feel sorry for people who answered didn't get the reward thats all

Comment: @Gandalf - I've 'dropped' bounties before as well.  But you have 7 days - if you're going to be away from the computer for that long you might consider not starting the bounty in the first place.

Comment: @Gandalf, what about your *Sorry guys this wasn't what I was looking for, I wanted to see how to do it using application context with bean injection ..* at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478729/jboss-messaging-jms/2537411#2537411 then? Seems to me that was not mentioned in your question?

Comment: @Gandalf I have dropped bounties myself but I reached the conclusion that it was my own damn fault: The system sends an E-Mail three days, and one day before the bounty expires. You can't really complain about not having been notified here.

Comment: Maybe you can try to contact a mod to have the bounty awarded. I'm not sure if they have the capabilities to do that, though.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. You should have gotten two email notifications as well as two SO site notifications that your bounty was closing. Once the bounty has started, it is the owner's responsibility to accept a suitable answer before the end of the bounty period.
2. Your question was a bit unclear; you posted an answer 11 hours ago that said "Sorry guys this wasn't what I was looking for, I wanted to see how to do it using application context with bean injection". This really should have been edited into the question 4-5 days ago, while the bounty was still running.
3. At the very least you could have provided comments on existing answers so others can see what did and didn't work for you. I count ONE comment on the answers.

Bounty is not magic fairy dust that magically makes the perfect answer appear -- **you have to put some effort into it too!**