# Unawarded bounty goes to highest voted answer if accepted answer is from before the bounty?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

This strikes me as strange... there's a [question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed/3033464)... and then a bounty was offered. (as my answer was submitted before, I understand it was ineligible for auto-selection)

However, then my answer was accepted, and the bounty seems to have not been awarded, and thus the bounty went to another answer.

This seems unusual to me. Not that I mind - I'm not going to lose sleep over 100 rep - but it struck me as flat out confusing.

Even if the accepted answer is from before the time the bounty was offered, in the event of an un-awarded bounty, shouldn't the accepted answer take precedence? Or is this by design, and I'm just missing something?

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/in-a-bounty-scenario-can-an-answer-from-before-the-bounty-be-automatically-accep) suggests that "the assumption is that the bounty owner was not satisfied with any of the existing answers at the time the bounty was started" but I can't help but wonder that if that's the case... why would they accept one?

(or am I completely misinterpreting everything, and that bounty was in fact not auto-awarded?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The bounty system changed recently](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/), and it's possible simply that the person who marked your answer as accepted didn't realize it doesn't award the bounty anymore on the way (unlike the earlier system).

Then, the bounty went to the highest voted new answer, automatically, since it wasn't attributed.

Comment: I see... "all bounties are completely independent of and unrelated to accepting an answer." Still feels... unusual to me.