# Will a bounty be automatically awarded to an answer that was posted before the bounty, if it has been edited?

Tags: support, edits, bounties

Similar to this question [In a bounty scenario, can an answer from before the bounty be automatically accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/in-a-bounty-scenario-can-an-answer-from-before-the-bounty-be-automatically-acce)

But in my case ([Make Gmail send automatic canned responses for email it gets via POP](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22153/make-gmail-send-automatic-canned-responses-for-email-it-gets-via-pop)) one of the replies was edited after the bounty was posted.  However it still does not answer the question.  (It was basically edited to clarify that it poses a solution that does not fit the original question.)   Also in my case, the question was not originally mine.  I tried to use a bounty to revive the existing question rather than attempting to post a duplicate. (However, I am disappointed that the bounty resulted in very few additional views of my question, and no additional suggestions.)

No one has posted a new reply or edited an old one to answer the question.  So I would like the bounty to not be awarded.  (I know that I won't get the points back.  I don't care about that.)  I am just wondering if that edited reply, which was also accepted by the original poster, will automatically get the bounty awarded or not.

Comment: In my opinion, the linked question (both the one I linked, and the one mine is marked a duplicate of) does not clearly answer my question about whether **editing** a response makes it count as a new response for the purposes of auto-awarding.  I had already read the FAQ when I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The automatic bounty awarding process will only award the bounty to an answer posted after the bounty was started. Edits are disregarded.

> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started

<sup>Source: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I had read that, but wasn't 100% sure that edits would be disregarded.