# Please always update the documentation (FAQ) on feature changes

Tags: support, faq-update-request

I do read the SO blog, and I roughly read meta, but I'm still often surprised by unexpected changes or additions of features. It appears that documenting is not exactly a forte of the SO team, and this makes it difficult to be up-to-date on the system itself.

Don't get me wrong, I really do like your improvements, and I also noticed that very important matters (e.g. rep rule changes) are announced in advance and quite well described. But judging from the related questions, there is indeed a decent amount of confusion caused by missing documentation.

Would it be possible for you, dear SO team, to update the FAQ pages and write a detailed changelog more often?

Comment: Related: [Monthly Summary of What’s New](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47433/), and also [Use a banner to announce when new SO blog articles on SO operations are posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43512/) and [A better notification of significant modifications on the trilogy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48087/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is documented here

[Monthly Summary of What's New](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47433/monthly-summary-of-whats-new)

But apparently nobody reads that.

(which is what I've been saying all along -- either the feature is discoverable and relatively self-explanatory when "experienced", or we've failed ..)

Comment: Did *you* document this? Or did the community have to do it.

Comment: Features must be discoverable and relatively self-explanatory because 99.99% (maybe more) of the users will never see Meta, the blog, or other notifications.  However, those power users that would read a dedicated notification feed (i.e. Meta users) are the ones best situated to [provide feedback](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/05/on-working-remotely.html) on new features.

Comment: @gnoupi well, *I* documented it in multiple answers to Meta questions. :)

Comment: have to admit that updating the 4-5 duplicates about the same idea at each feature implemented is not ideal indeed. But hey, it reduces the todo list by a large amount each time :] Besides, about the latest change, it's not one which is really of the "confusing" kind. Not notifying for something like this is not really a big deal in itself. But I stand by my position for the ["game changing"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48087/) ones