# I wrongly downvoted an answer

Tags: support, voting, specific-question, down-votes

I finally realized my error, and tried to upvote it, but the site tells me the "vote is too old to be changed". Is there a way to me to donate some of my reputation to the user I wronged?

Comment: What answer is it? I'll edit it so you can change your vote.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26368/why-is-my-vote-now-too-old-to-be-changed

Comment: Not a dupe since it discusses a specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, and thanks for the edit George. I just upvoted it.

Comment: @George: How did you know what post it was?

Comment: @Fixed-Width the powers of deduction. I took his latest activity (where he answered a question) and looked at where he commented; the answers he commented on that had downvotes I assumed to be from him. I upvoted them and edited them.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your vote if the underlying post is edited. So leave a comment asking the owner to edit it, or if you have 2k+ rep, edit it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you edit your question with a link to the answer, one of us with the appropriate rep can edit it so you can change your vote. Once we do that, though, go straight to clicking "upvote," do **not** click the "downvote" to undo. (If you click "downvote" to undo, you won't be able to click "upvote" until it's edited again.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change your vote is if someone edits the question. Do you have editing rights? If not, ask someone else to edit the question so you can change your vote.

I'm not saying they will; but it's a work-around.

Comment: As of now, @GregS doesn't have editing rights yet: http://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/gregs