# Petition to remove accidental votes

Tags: support, stack-overflow, voting, down-votes, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I wrongly downvoted an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34251/i-wrongly-downvoted-an-answer)

I was reading questions on Stack Overflow with my iPad, and went to look at the +- votes of a question and each of its answers, but I instead accidentally downvoted every answer and the question. I did not realize it until a few hours later, with the result that the down-votes are now blocked. Is there any way to petition to remove my own accidental downvotes?  The question is [Save function in tuple without executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547128/python-save-function-in-tuple-without-executing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make a minor edit, or ask the poster by comment to make it, then you can remove/change the vote.

I've just made the edits, you should now be able to remove them.