# can't cancel a vote

Tags: bug, voting, locked-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Isn’t the “vote too old to be changed” a little too eager?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25202/isnt-the-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-a-little-too-eager)
>   [Why is my vote now too old to be changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26368/why-is-my-vote-now-too-old-to-be-changed)

I cant cancel a vote, I get "vote is too old" which is nice except I did a few seconds ago (the vote, not the canceling).

[MySQL Query - Result Table Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106478/mysql-query-result-table-name/2106502#2106502)

Comment: I believe the cutoff time for vote canceling is 5 seconds. It may be as high as 30 though.

Comment: The cutoff times are very aggressive on StackOverflow.  Much less so on the StackExchange sites.