# Sometimes able to remove vote mistakenly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting

[I've seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31765/voting-bug-so-mistakenly-lets-me-change-my-vote-1x-but-then-locks-it-at-that) and it's not the same]

Sometimes, when visiting a question that i voted on a long time ago, it lets me remove my vote while the page is loading but then locks the vote down so i can't fix it. Can this be fixed?

Comment: What's your example post as well as timeline to you voting and if it actually had an edit when re-voting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734960/which-are-unsolvable-problems-in-programming-world When i originally voted: a couple of weeks ago, up to a month i think, and it did have an edit

Comment: Are you sure the linked question isn't the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because the post was edited since you cast your original vote.

If the post has been edited, it is eligible for re-voting by anyone who previously voted on it.

Comment: What i mean is the page is loading and for whatever reason i unclick the vote then *immediately* (within 2 seconds) reclick the vote, but it only accepts the first one.

Comment: Sounds like the revote-after-edit problem to me.

Comment: David thornley: ???