# I cannot vote for this question, what's wrong?

Tags: support, voting, locked-votes

I try to upvote for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/131160/windows-7-explorer-doesnt-use-details-view-in-folders-with-media), but SU system message says:
Vote too old to be changed, unless this question is edited.

I have never voted for this question before, so this seems like a bug which doesn't let me vote. When I click on 0 (vote count), there are 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes. Anyone experiencing this kind of error?

(The same error is generated when I try to downvote)

[image]

Comment: In any event it would be no repro for the OP because it was asked in 2010 but "edited Oct 30 '14 at 14:11". With the possibility of it being a dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31765/voting-bug-so-mistakenly-lets-me-change-my-vote-1x-but-then-locks-it-at-that and one upvote in nine years.

Comment: waithing for some time and upvoting again will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you never tried to vote on that question, and immediately reverted that vote?

After a few moments, you can no longer retract any vote, and as you have already voted in the eyes of the system, then the system, to prevent gaming, doesn't allow you to change your vote, even if it was a retracted vote that ended being a net 0.

Comment: I'm sure of it. See my screenshot. If I voted for this question, there would be electric-blue upvote or downvote indicators.

Comment: @Mehper "... and immediately reverted that vote" is the key. A reverted vote won't show up as a coloured arrow. This can often happen by accident, when clicking an arrow twice, thus effectively cancelling the vote.

Comment: I just tried to upvote immediately as I opened the question, and I don't remember if I accidentally retracted the vote. Let's say I have upvoted a question, and immediately retracted my vote. As I use no votes in this case, won't I be able to vote on that question again (unless question is changed)?

Comment: @Mehper: To "the system", you have already voted. This is [status-bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31765/voting-bug-so-mistakenly-lets-me-change-my-vote-1x-but-then-locks-it-at-that). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vote-too-old

Comment: I just tried voting on an answer, retracting my vote and re-voting a while later, and it worked just fine.