# Upvote has been registered a downvote on SO?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I just upvoted an answer to my question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201355/ms-entity-framework-vs-nhibernate-and-its-derived-contribs-fluentnhibernate-lin) and my upvote seems to have been registered as a downvote. This is the answer #3, Tom Bushell. I wonder how can I change this as SO says "Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited.".

What went wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you misclicked the arrow, I doubt there's a bug that big that hasn't been found.

As a workaround, you can leave a comment asking someone to trivially edit the answer, and then you can change your vote.
There, I edited it for you, you can now change the vote

**Edit**: Apparently you could only upvote to 0, so the -1 wasn't from you, it was from someone else, and your problem was that the upvote didn't applied in the first place

Comment: @Downvoter: Agreed, indeed. Thanks for your pompt answer. Despite the edit performed on the answer, it will only let me upvote to 0, while a +1 vote is deserved by the answerer. Is there another way so that I can make this vote up once again to give the answerer his +1 vote deserved?

Comment: If you could only upvote to 0, then the -1 wasn't from you, it was from someone else, and your problem was that the upvote didn't applied

Comment: Good conclusion Sherlock, that downvote couldn't have been Will's then! Given the additional *Vote too old to be changed:* I guess @Will somehow *undid* the upvote by clicking it twice. Undoing a vote does not invalidate the timer that locks further changing of the (non-existing) vote.

Comment: That's it! That's when I wish to upvote an already upvoted answer that it removes my preceding upvote, then, I am unable to upvote back. How come can we remove an upvote by clicking the upvoting button, and we cannot set it back? If it is so that the vote is too old to be changed, why can I change it for the worse, and not for the good?

Comment: @Will, I don't think you can vote either way if the timeframe has passed. This timeframe apparently is needed as some users are gaming the system by *temporarily* downvoting other answers to get more votes for their own post, or something like that... See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046.