# What happened to close reason "no longer relevant"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

I know a few close reasons have been merged, but **no longer relevant** was useful, and now it's not here anymore.

What should be use in its place?

Comment: Here's an example I wanted to use it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38707

Comment: A post-it on your monitor to hide it. That way as it moves down the page, you can keep it from view.

Comment: Or get five other people to flag it as spam and it'll be distappeareded!

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38676/close-reasons-have-gone-missing-previously-closed-as-such-affected

Comment: Here's a question for 'no longer relevant': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234032/unknown-scope-of-function-in-class - I've used 'too localized' as a poor surrogate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say **too localized**:

> This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Emphasis mine. Whoa man I can see *through time*.

Comment: Yep.  The list of close reasons was getting too lengthy, and there's little reason to break it out into more fine detail as to why it's too localized.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have another example of "no longer relevant": [this question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/96613/gmail-chat-doesnt-work-in-ie8).

The problem "solved itself", no accepted answer, nothing. It's a typical case of a "situation" which is no longer relevant. "Too localized" would be weird for that kind, really.

And yes, closing such questions [has a point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36296/should-we-close-old-questions-with-no-more-feedback-as-no-longer-relevant-on-s), because if someone comes with a similar problem, this existing question won't be of any use for him, and yet will be a living "duplicate".

Comment: The user should be prompted to answer their own question and then accept that answer.

Comment: It solved itself automagically, so there's no real answer to the question to accept except ponies

Comment: garbage in, garbage out -- question deleted