# Should old questions that are no longer relevant be closed as too localized (meta)?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, meta, too-localized

Meta is way more affected by time than the other sites. There are a lot of questions that are not useful anymore ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42870/rough-reputation-lost-estimating-program-for-new-reputation-rule)).

Should we close them as too localized?
It seems correct according to the definition:

> too localized
>   This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

We could let them undeleted for a sense of history, but I see no reason for them to remain opened.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why bother? What's so bad about open questions that are old and no longer looked at?

Comment: Because it's cleaner @ear

Comment: And we have to be CLEAN!  (Just read Give Me Liberty (Frank Miller, Dave Gibbons) again... blame the Surgeon General ;-))

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Most of these, unless they have specific reasons to remain (eg they contain useful and not confusing and now historically *irrelevant* (or, worse, *wrong*) information) **should be deleted**.

So I vote, flag them for mod attention with the text "candidate for deletion?"

Comment: I agree, but even if these questions contain useful information, they probably should have the best answers added to the FAQ in some way (if the topic isn't covered already) and be deleted, instead of keeping them around as quasi-duplicates.

Comment: maybe there should be a more public way to handle this. See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836839/php-problem-parse-error-syntax): It has no value for future generations and the OP got his solution; however, just wordlessly deleting it may put off the OP (he's new) and the top answerer. I mod-flagged it as a candidate for deletion but I don't think this is the optimal way to go

Comment: @Eat "this question" has been deleted, so it's a perfect example for not deleting it: your comment doesn't make much sense without the question's text.

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about this when I finished up the DevDays retagging the other day.

There were a few really time-sensitive questions that have zero relevance now (i.e., "I can't go to DevDays, does anyone want to buy my ticket?"). It's really just noise now.

At the very least, I think specific questions like that should be closed if they've been solved (which is highly likely).

Comment: yeah the "noise" should be flagged for deletion

Answer (score 3):

#### Repository of questions that are too localized (add your own/edit as questions get closed).

(None right now.)

Big thanks to @Random for closing most of these with his super-duper awesomely awesome mod powers.

Comment: I just put in my 12 votes for today. I'll come back tomorrow for some more.

Comment: @Chacha: I think a mod dropped by and took care of a lot of the original ones (most of them appear to be deleted now).

Comment: Alternatively you could say the other mods chose to keep that last batch open while random was off closing questions on SU.

Comment: it's true that @random is kind of awesome

Answer (score 3):

### Not Necessarily!

IF they're truly not relevant (i.e. real old), like old DevDays questions then they should be closed and left for historical purposes.

If they're not relevant because the Team disagrees with the discussion, then once the discussion is not active anymore, they can be closed and left for historical purposes.

Closing takes care of all non-relevant situations.

Deletions should be used for offensive, spam or completely off-topic questions (like programming questions on Meta).

#### What's a Community without History?

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a close reason of `No longer relevant`. It was very useful for *exactly* this situation, especially in meta. I wish we had it back. This is going to become more of an issue as time passes, especially in meta and Super User.

Of the choices, "Closed as too localized" is your best option.

This was discussed here: [What happened to close reason “no longer relevant”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38710/what-happened-to-close-reason-no-longer-relevant)