# Remove questions with moderator tags from the Unanswered list

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, moderator-tags

The red tags/moderator tags/status tags — except for [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), perhaps — on Meta indicate that a mod has considered a feature request or bug and made a decision about how to handle it. In other words, they tend to equal "this is the official answer from the admins."

Over a hundred questions in the Unanswered list are marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) right now, mostly quick bug reports that don't require long explanatory answers. Depending on how you look at it, they'll never be answered, they can't be answered and/or they've effectively already been answered. Could questions with red tags be filtered out of the Unanswered list entirely?

Comment: 0 I like no-ops.

Comment: what about [status-declined] requests that actually most users *want*? And sometimes even happen to be changed into [status-completed] at a later point?

Comment: @Tobias, they'll still show up if you search for the tags. I guess this comes down to how people use the Unanswered tab. I do it when looking for things that haven't been addressed at all, and regardless of what might happen in the future, anything tagged `[status-declined]` has technically been addressed.

Comment: @Pops what's the problem with these questions being frequent?

Answer (score 12):

This is still a problem.

- The highest voted question, the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), has 0 answers. All the content (which is prodigious and important) is contained in the question body.
- There are [63 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/status-completed) which are [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- There are [14 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/status-declined) which are [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- There are [9 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/status-norepro) which are [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Fortunately, it seems to have gone down in the past year.  However, it hasn't been eliminated.

For some questions, such as tag merge requests, a simple, one line answer "It has been done" is sufficient.  For example, see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109806/tag-merge-request-codecs-and-codec).  There is resistance to the need for answering instead of just retagging.

Answers to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) questions should have a description of the feature in the answers.  For an example of what to do, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message/66241#66241) or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2373#2373). For an example of what not to do, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104879/option-to-give-a-reason-for-disputing-or-declining-a-flag/109931#comment284278_109931) which was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), which failed to notify the OP, leaving the OP [to speculate that it had been done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104879/option-to-give-a-reason-for-disputing-or-declining-a-flag/109931#109931) when the effects were observed sometime later.  The OP had no reference to [implementation discussion elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106039/proposed-flag-decline-reasons), a post which was not marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) posts should contain reasoning as to why the feature was not implemented.  Important content like this does not belong in the comments.

Comment: Update: Now 95 unanswered, 16 declined, 11 norepro.  It's going up!

Comment: Removing questions tagged as [tag:status-whatever] from the Unanswered list should be implemented for all Meta sites, not only the main one. Of course, I agree that they should have an answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes there are 105 unanswered marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but that's out of over 1,100 questions total, so I don't see this as a problem, nor do I think it needs special SE programmer team attention.

If you want, go ahead and resurrect [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49466/should-old-questions-that-are-no-longer-relevant-be-closed-as-too-localized-meta). I'd support closing the ones that are legitimately completed and/or no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2):

**Just an idea:** There are >120 questions tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). And they are filling up the unanswered section.

**We all know this is a problem.**

Maybe we should create a whole entire tab on the questions list for tags like [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

This tab should be named 'moderator-tagged', and will show up as a separate filter tab on the unanswered list. I feel we don't need to remove them, just move them to another area where they will create less complaint.

If people really want answers, they deserve them.