# Bonus moderation flags for users who have an extremely helpful flag record for the day

Tags: feature-request, flags, rate-limiting

It seems like a bit of a backtrack to limit users to only a certain number of moderation flags in the day. I understand why the limit is in place, so people can't "spam" moderators with useless flags (is this even the reason?). But those of us who use them appropriately should be able to continue flagging things that we find to be inappropriate. I've used all of my flags for the day, at least the normal, non-spam-offensive flags. So now if I see something which is not an answer, etc I am unable to flag anything further until the magical reset point at midnight UTC.

It would be nice if there was some way for helpful flaggers to get additional flag votes during the consecutive day if their flags continue to prove helpful to moderators. I think a good implementation would be to still allow the same limit and forbid them from continuing to flag until a majority of those flags have already been reviewed. If the user maintains a helpful record throughout the day, they should continue to receive 3 or 5 more flag votes as they continue running out so they can keep flagging things here and there and remain helpful. Once the user gets 2 or 3 declined flags for the day, they will cease to receive additional flag votes for the day and any remaining *bonus* flag votes they had should be revoked.

If this can't be implemented, could someone explain *why* it shouldn't and/or why the limit for number of moderation flags per day should remain limited as such?

Comment: This seems sensible. The only thing that I can think of against it is that mods are now encouraged to [dismiss nearly every flag as "helpful"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106047/), meaning there's no way to discriminate between "very helpful" and "marginally helpful" flagger.

Comment: @Problem: Perhaps what is really needed is another option. Maybe moderators should be able to mark as declined, dismissed, or helpful, in which a dismissed flag will have no effect whatsoever on the user's flag weight of daily flag record.

Comment: I'd love to have the neutral option to dismiss too. I feel dirty dismissing some flags as helpful when in fact they aren't, and I can't think of compelling reasons to decline them instead.

Comment: I think comment flags already work like this. Some days I've got through 100+

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high

Comment: How about a user gets back every approved flag and can cast it again immediately?

Comment: In the worst case that a user goes malicious, the user can spam the queue with nearly 100 flags (normal flags, spam/offensive flag, comment flag). Increasing the number of flags per day may make the problem above worse, but giving user back a flag for every (n) helpful flag doesn't change the number of unreviewed flags of the user at any time.