# I see four different displayed messages for declined flags - in what condition does each one of them get triggered?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

Whenever I go through my flagging history, I see some flags that were declined.  However, I see **four different messages** for them:

> 1. *"Declined"*
>
> [image]
>
> 2. *"Declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*
>
> [image]
>
> 3. *"Declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"*
>
> [image]
>
> 4. *"Declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"*
>
> [image]

Which condition triggers one message, while another condition triggers another one?

Comment: The messages are not described in the [FAQ about comment flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work). I guess they were thought to be self explanatory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2., 3. and 4. are the [standard responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106039/295232) when ♦ moderators decline your *post* flag. They can opt to write a custom message, too.

1. can happen in multiple cases; it's the standard for a declined *comment* flag (♦ moderators just dismiss those if they don't agree, without an option to leave a response). This also happens when you cast a *close* flag and the community unanimously votes to leave the question open in the review queue.