# Remove [status-completed] posts from Unanswered Questions list

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderator-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove questions with moderator tags from the Unanswered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65429/remove-questions-with-moderator-tags-from-the-unanswered-list)

This is just a suggestion, but could we get meta posts with moderator-only tags removed from the Unanswered list, since they were clearly attended to in some way?

Example here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131394/102937

Currently, it requires posting a CW answer with a sufficient number of characters to get by the Low Quality filter, and someone else to upvote it.

Comment: Hmm, I've been questioning the utility of showing [meta-tag:status-norepro] on the bugs tab too.