# When should questions be closed as "too localised" on MSO?

Tags: support, meta, close-reasons, too-localized

Under what circumstances would it be appropriate to close a question as "too localised" on MSO? Unlike the other sites, the purpose of meta is to provide support rather than build a QA database, so I don't see how a meta question being localised is a problem.

Comment: The meta is strong with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd love to have some data related to the close reasons, however it's [not available yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51689/close-reason-for-close-votes-in-the-data-dump). So, subjectively speaking, most of the time on Meta, questions are closed as duplicates (mostly), off-topic, or noise/pointless.

Too Localized is mostly used to clean up questions that are no longer relevant (invoking the "specific moment in time" clause of the close reason) -- see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49466/should-old-questions-that-are-no-longer-relevant-be-closed-as-too-localized-meta).

This is pretty much a housecleaning activity (with the ultimate goal of deletion most of the time). This would apply to posts such as:

- Completed account merge questions, and other specific support requests
- "OMG Stack Overflow is downnnn"-type questions where it's been resolved that it's only down for the post author, or the situation has been resolved
- Feature requests that are so specific or localized in a way that would benefit very few users (rare)
- Questions based on some existing condition which has now changed (for example, questions about the previous system to award a bounty)

Note: localized bug reports (where no one can repro) are the exception to this -- these should be mod-tagged `[status-norepro]` instead of being closed. The reason for that is if someone else has the same problem down the road, they can add an answer to the question and give it a bump to get help, or to prod a dev to (re)investigate.

Answer (score 0):

The first topic that jumps to mind is [gay horses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gay+horse).

Other reasons are for questions about *specific* questions, users and answers on SO, rather than about the rules and policies of the system in general.

It’s funny that there’s [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49466/should-old-questions-that-are-no-longer-relevant-be-closed-as-too-localized-meta) in the sidebar claiming the opposite problem, that meta questions are *more* vulnerable to the effects of time.

Comment: I'd say the "gay horses" question should have been closed as *not a real question*, I don't see how the problem is it being too specific. Also, is it really off-topic to ask a question about a problem user, or where a particular question should go?

Comment: I was thinking more like "This user harassed me what should I do", or "Why was my question closed?" The close reason of "Too localized" used to be "No longer relevant", which more clearly included those reasons.