# Please make the default view on the reputation page be a shorter period of time

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-page

The new reputation page has an interesting quirk that it allows spans much greater than the old 90 day limit we used to have. It also provides data in a slightly more condensed fashion, though equally with more words.

The problem is that it defaults to showing your entire history. I can't actually open [Jon Skeet's reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation) without IE8 throwing multiple alerts that a script is slowing down the computer and should be terminated.

And in most scenarios, I'm not really interested in seeing the entire play-by-play of someone's entire history. It's the more recent events, either within the past day or the past week, that are of interest to me. I can get this information and not pay attention to the whole of it by just expanding the recent day. But it still needs to load everything initially, which can take some time.

Could we allow timespans of some sort? Kinda like how we have the "week", "month", "quarter", "year", and "all" for the Users and the Leagues, could we have similar breakouts for our reputation page? And, consequently, default this to a week? Or is this already in the works?

Comment: Paging within the time spans would be nice as well, given that the longer spans will still have lengthy lists.