# Please add a combined view of recent reputation changes and responses to the user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, recent-activity, reputation-page

On the user profile, I would like to see a combined view of recent changes, e.g. in the form of a "Recent" tab page<sup>1</sup>. This would be a sort of aggregated "News stream" of the kind that most people are familiar with from websites like Facebook.

This page would display:

- Answers received
- Comments received
- Edits made
- Upvotes/downvotes received
- Changes in favorites
- ...

The view should be compact, so displaying all items as on the reputation tab is not desirable. Instead, the time period could be configurable (day, week, month, last visit, with last visit being the default).

The recent tab should be available with a single click from the main menu.

I feel that this would be a clear improvement to the previous recent-envelope feature and to the current situation:

- All user-related information is now accessible from the user profile page
- Most of the features previously available can be retained in a very similar fashion which means less confusion for users.
- To see *all* recent changes (responses + rep changes) it is no longer necessary to check multiple tabs in the user profile

The feature request is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83265/please-make-the-default-view-on-the-reputation-page-be-a-shorter-period-of-time).

<sup>1</sup><sub>I understand that the profile page is currently under change, but at the moment such a functionality is missing. Maybe such a feature is already planned; however, there is no information available how the new page would look in the future - hence the request.</sub>

Comment: It appears the new profile page is in testing on meta.SO now. :)