# StackOverflow Hidden Gems

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I like stackoverflow a lot but strangely some things are really counter intuitive. I browsed around the site but I'm not sure if the feature I'm looking for exist.

- Is there any email notification ?
- Can you get a really specific rss feed like top question for php / week
- Is there a blog or something to know when things change and complain about. For example until recently I could click on my user name on top and I could see a quick overview of what's going on in my account + a notification icon was displayed over the username ( I miss this feature)

Comment: Click on "meta" in the top menu.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com is the site you want to visit to ask questions *about* stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any email notification ?

There are options for email notifications. You just have to remember to enable them.
Go to you profile page by clicking on your name-> find the Prefs Tab button. At the bottom you will find a checkbox for mail notifications.

> Is there a blog?

There is a little blog link at the footer section. Updates and upcomings are usually discussed there.

Comment: Where can I enable mail notifications ?

Comment: @danip: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: I don't think it's working. I activated but not emails.

Comment: @dani it's only once per day there's no instant email option. For this you have the StackExchange Global Inbox - you'll see number in red circle in the top left of the page when there's new answer to your question or comment on post you made. (Either question or answer)

Comment: @shadow - how should the user know this? I don't think the usability is very good on this one. Also this might be ok for other sites, but for stackexchange should really be 1 hour or so. I guess is hard to send all those emails so I understand.

Comment: @dani same way like everyone come to know eventually.. by asking and looking for information. :) I believe they have good reason for daily only emails, doubt they'll change it - just stick around every hour or so and you'll see "vital" changes in your SE inbox above. :)

Comment: @Shadow,@dani: Sending updates every now and then will put a lot of stress on the system. Therefore, it's good to just send them at a regular interval(1 day in this case). It will cause less stress on server and easy to implement.

Comment: Also @Shadow, @dani, @Gunner: it's important to remember that [Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) [hates](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/09/when-email-goes-bad.html) [email](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/is-email-efail.html)

Comment: @David good catch! This indeed might explain many things. :)

Comment: @Shadow: well, I had to learn *something* reading that there blog... =]

Answer (score 0):

> Until recently I could click on my
> user name on top and I could see a
> quick overview of what's going on in
> my account

You mean the Envelope - it was replaced with new GUI as you can read about [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446).
It's still being refined so please be patient. :)

Not all is lost though, you can still see the page it used to link to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/
However you won't see any notification when there's a change in favorites anymore.

Comment: Is this page not linked in any way ?

Comment: Also there was a number displayed over the username. That was a good feature I miss.

Comment: @dani your reputation amount is now link to your own "Reputation Tab" which display your daily reputation changes - guess that's the closest you can find. What number was over the username? Don't remember such.

Comment: @shadow - it was a number in red circle over the username or the arrow ( i'm not 100% sure which of those 2 ), the number represented the new answers

Comment: @dani that's the StackExchange Global Inbox I was talking about before, it's not related to the user name it's far to the left of the top menu and it's still working exactly as before.

Comment: @shadow - I understand that but I'm telling you, before the site update the same functionality was applied to the username, at it was a Local status for the current site

Comment: @dan sorry, I remember only the Envelope that was turning bright yellow when there were changes. :-(

Comment: @shodow - you might be right :), ok so I miss the envelope thing, and I don't like ajax status then.

Comment: @dani - join the club.... believe me people here tried to fight it. Bottom line, we just have to accept it. :)

Comment: is there a discussion about this specific topic ?

Comment: @dani - there are several: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/recent-favorite-changes and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83286/can-more-of-the-functionality-of-the-old-envelope-be-added-to-the-new-drop-down-m and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83270/please-add-a-combined-view-of-recent-reputation-changes-and-responses-to-the-user feel free to voice your opinion as comment in any of those.