# `users/recent` page no longer exists?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Bring back the Recent Activity option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86430/bring-back-the-recent-activity-option)
>   [Can we have the /users/recent page back? Or an alternative summary page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86027/can-we-have-the-users-recent-page-back-or-an-alternative-summary-page)

The page `http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent` no longer works, it says it is not found.  Has SO finally decided to eliminate it altogeher?

Comment: Please vote to re-open http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86430/bring-back-the-recent-activity-option-closed.