# Can more of the functionality of the old envelope be added to the new drop-down menu?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, notifications

Buried deep in the now deleted Eeeek post, I had a well-hidden feature-request. [Grace Note encouraged me to make it a *real* feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83253/what-topics-can-be-discussed-here/83257#83257), so here it is. The new drop-down menu is nice, but some crucial functionality of the envelope is missing:

I'd like those numbers behind "revisions" and "favorites" (and maybe also "reputation") **clickable**! After clicking I'd like to see, e.g., the list of recent favorite changes that at the moment can still be found on the `/recent` page. Moreover, one very important column is missing: I don't care so much for "today", the first column should be "since last visit". This was the greatest advantage of that envelope; it brought me up-to-date efficiently.

Finally, I sorely miss the "orange envelope notification" of changes in my favorites. This was a quick way for me to check if something important happened here on meta.SO. How can I do that in the future? *(This part is not yet completed, unfortunately, although the* `/recent` *page together with it's nice "favorites" tab is [going to die very soon](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/).)*

**UPDATE** (Mar 17): The numbers for reputation are now clickable. The page behind the link shows even more details than `/recent`. Moreover, if you click on "reputation" (in the left column), then the changes since the last visit of that page are highlighted (which is similar to what `/recent` did), so the *reputation* part of my request could be considered as completed. Nice!
Tim Post had an additional idea: Would it be possible that "the reputation link indicated somehow that there were unviewed reputation changes"?

Mar 18: Another thing that's missing from the `/recent` page is the "revisions" tab that notified me of *other users* editing *my* posts (as opposed to the "revisions" tab in my "activity" that shows posts *I* edited). For example, now I didn't get any notification that Marc Gravell had tagged [my bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83689/sorting-of-question-in-the-active-view-is-broken) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).
**UPDATE** (Mar 30) Either I was completely mistaken here, or it has now been implemented that clicking "revisions" immediately shows me the recent revisions that happened to my posts. Nice! Unfortunately I don't get a clear notification anymore, but I can get used to that.

Comment: I asked a link to the "recent" view that is still active - guess this request will suit as well.

Comment: Similar requests can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83270/please-add-a-combined-view-of-recent-reputation-changes-and-responses-to-the-user, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83265/please-make-the-default-view-on-the-reputation-page-be-a-shorter-period-of-time

Comment: The "Recent activity" page is still accessible at http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/(your-id). But I miss the envelope too...

Comment: @Thomas: I know it's available, but Jeff has already said that it won't stay for long (don't find the link right now).

Comment: +1 for the "Since last visit" functionality

Comment: Yup, I instinctively clicked on those numbers the first time, *expecting* them to go somewhere - "drill-down" is just second nature :)

Comment: It seems that the numbers for reputation are now clickable. Perhaps this is on the way of being implemented!

Comment: @Grace: Thanks for pointing that out; see my update.

Comment: I believe the "since I last looked at this page" part has been [implemented too](http://i.imgur.com/7N2oE.png), at least for the reputation tab (note the highlight in the linked screenshot). I'm not sure if it sticks around indefinitely if you don't look at the tab for a while, though.

Comment: @Tim: In your screenshot, I think "today" is highlighted, and that's it.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Ah, yes, that's true if you access the page via the drop down time span links it seems. I went to it directly from my profile, and in that case the highlighting seemed to corresponded with the events contributing to the +15 indicator in the tab (though it's a bit hard to tell given there was only one). Now that the 15 has disappeared, if I go to the tab in this manner again, the highlighting is gone.

Comment: @Tim: _You're right!_ When I click on "reputation" in the drop-down, then I see the top part (since last visit) highlighted; when I try again, the highlighted part is gone. That's it!

Comment: @HendrikVogt Hooray! What might be nice is if the reputation link indicated somehow that there were unviewed reputation changes (like the profile tab does), to make that behaviour a little more apparent to people.

Comment: @Tim: Right, that would be helpful indeed. I'll further update my question sometime soon.

Comment: w/r/t your last edit.. what? that's what this is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=responses&rfilter=revisions -- a list of revisions to my post by *other users*, is it not?

Comment: @Jeff: Ah well, thanks, my bad. I actually don't get to see _your_ responses tab (your link sends me to [your info page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=stats)), but I do get to see mine. However, the revisions are somewhat lost among the other responses _unless one explicitly looks at the "revisions" tab of the responses_. As far as I remember, the envelope got orange not only on favourite changes but also on those revisions (or am I mistaken?) - this is what I meant with "notification" in my last edit.

Comment: @Jeff, just to say where my confusion originated: On the `/recent` page I see _both_ "responses" and "revisions" on the same level, and that's what I'm used to. On the new user page, "revisions" is a _subtab_ of "responses".

Answer (score 6):

The last time you clicked on the reputation and responses tab on your user page are tracked, like so.

[image]

The indicators tell you how much rep, and how many responses, since the last time you clicked those tabs.

Comment: Niceness; does that happen with favourites too?

Comment: @Richard - it will, some form of this will debut tomorrow

Comment: @Nick: Great, I appreciate that. Hope it will also show recent comments in my favourites.

Comment: @Nick, @Jeff: [On the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/) it says "We still have some work to do on the favorites support". I'm still hoping for something resembling _somehow_ the "favorites" tab of the `/recent` page.

Comment: You've now killed the /users/recent URL too. Any news on replacement favorites support or is the current tab the final version?