# Notification of updates to my favorite questions

Tags: discussion, favorites-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox)

There was a feature previously in SE sites which used to show the "envelope" in yellow color whenever there is any update for the questions marked as favorite. Since the envelope is no more available on SE sites, where can I find that functionality now in new SE layout?

In short: How will I know if any of my favorite questions have had any updates?

Comment: A related post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83414/any-option-to-add-follow-for-a-post-and-get-notified-when-answers-avaialble

Comment: @Gunner - yes. I saw your post too. Somehow co-incidently, it seems that our questions were posted at exactly same time with difference in probably miliseconds. ;)

Comment: Telepathy maybe.. but the real reason is it's an useful feature that everyone would want.

Comment: @Gunner - Agreed. Definitely with you on this.

Comment: This is one of the things I requested/asked here: [Can more of the functionality of the old envelope be added to the new drop-down menu?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83286/155585)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Stackexchange button and it has a inbox. Wish that has updates on favourite questions too.

Comment: Should be in a different tab, though.