# Any option to Add Follow for a post and get notified when Answers available

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox)

Suppose someone asked a question which I am not able to answer but would like to get updates on.

One way we can do is to add it to our Favorites and follow it from there. But this will not give us any notification in our SE Inbox (number highlighted in red).

Is it possible to add a feature so we can follow a particular question and get notified about it?

Comment: If the *possible* duplicate I linked to doesn't work you could try subscribing to the question's RSS feed.

Comment: It doesn't fully solve it actually. Marking as favorite doesn't give any sort of notifications. I think it has been removed and there is another post open addressing that.

Comment: This is one of the things I requested here: [Can more of the functionality of the old envelope be added to the new drop-down menu?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83286/155585)

Comment: @Hendrik, @Gunner, [here's the place](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox) to follow up on this particular feature.

Comment: @Gunner, given the accepted answer: is this still a feature request? I guess it can be retagged to `[support]` instead?

Comment: Maybe both, I added the support tag also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you scroll all the way down to the bottom of a question page, on the right side you'll find a little rss icon with the text "question feed" next to it.  Updates won't show up on Stack Overflow itself, but you will see them come in via your favorite rss reader.  That should do what you want.

Comment: True, however this sort of functionality isn't integrated with the UI in the way that [an inbox message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox) would provide the same service, but with, I believe, a more consistent UI.