# Sorting of question in the "active" view is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, sorting

The picture says it all (feel free to add free-hand circles):

[image]

I had already two different versions of this strange behaviour, having some hours old question in-between the *really* active ones.

Comment: which site is this on? ... tex.se

Comment: This is my fault, Marc is working on a fix

Comment: @waffles: Ah, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Richard: Sorry, I should have said that. Thanks for pointing out tex.se.

Comment: k; we know what this is and how to fix it; looking in a few minutes...

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for looking into it. Any progress so far? (The degree of messiness is varying ...)

Comment: @Hendrik - just testing

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess.. "activity" also includes votes, it seems, because if you look at this one

- [Use autoref with minted and its listing environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13760)

And click through the OP and answerer's profiles, then the new whiz bang reputation page, it shows votes/voted in the last 13-14 minutes.

Tracking through the other questions, any comment or vote seems to also count as "activity".

Comment: That might be an explanation of this "feature", thanks.

Comment: actually it included any number of things; should be fixed now though

Comment: @Marc So we guessed