# Web Apps - Newest Questions

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, questions

The [Newest Questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) tab on Web Apps is periodically displaying 0 questions.

[image: image of New Questions tab with 0 questions, complete with hand-drawn circles]

Comment: I'm not seeing this. I get 4000+ questions.

Comment: @ChrisF - Yes, it's not all the time.  I have had it about 8-10 times this morning.  They disappear then come back back then disappear again. very strange

Comment: Ah - missed the "periodically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh; fix [one thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83689/sorting-of-question-in-the-active-view-is-broken), break the other ;p

Should work now; if not, let me know.

Comment: I like how @Waffles gets you to clear up his mess :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83689/sorting-of-question-in-the-active-view-is-broken#comment-205048

Comment: @Barry - we work different timezones; if it is more convenient for someone who is "at work", then why not? And to be fair, the blank page was 100% me - corner case relating to cached data