# Ordering of questions on the main page is broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions

This is the first time I've seen this. I opened DIY SE main page and here's how the list looked like:

[image]

it looks just fine except the top two questions are swapped.

I've seen [this rather old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83689/132564), maybe it's a similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been this way for a long time. When there's an edit or a new answer to a question, the displayed data is updated immediately, but it may take a moment for the sort order to be updated (retrieving data for a particular question is much cheaper than doing all kinds of sorting, thus the latter is more heavily cached).

As long as the delay is below a minute or so (like in your example where it's 38 seconds), this should be acceptable. Beyond that – like in the old report you found – it's probably a bug.