# Can we please get an option for the "envelope" feature back?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, recent-activity, activity-dropdown

The new dropdown is nice eye candy, but the "envelope" notification had better functionality.

Is there any plans to bring it back as an option perhaps?

Pretty please?

**edit**

With the old interface I could tell at a glance that "something" has happened. With 1 click, I could see everything that had changed since the last time I looked.

Now I have to click (or mouseover) to see what happened, then remember what it looked like the last time I saw. It just seems like a bit of a pain just to find out if someone upvoted/commented/answered a post.

If the dropdown had a notification, that something happened, and only showed what happened since the last time, that would be great.

Comment: What functionality exactly are you missing?

Comment: "Is there any plans to bring it back as an option perhaps?" No, actually, it seems deadset not to bring it back. Consider instead [suggesting improvements to the new system that mimic the features and functionality that you think are missing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83286/can-more-of-the-functionality-of-the-old-envelope-be-added-to-the-new-drop-down-m).

Comment: It never worked reliably anyway... I say good riddance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, we have lost a lot of functionality.  This question is a dupe, but they deleted [the post it was a dupe of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope), so you'll have to view a [cached copy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OWjGefanjxMJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope+eeeek+what+happened+to+my+envelope&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com).  [There is a greasemonkey script in that question that will give you the envelope back.](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OWjGefanjxMJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope+eeeek+what+happened+to+my+envelope&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com#82557)

Comment: You have to be 10K to get a greasemonkey script?

Comment: @Moshe, you have to be 10k to get see the answer that has the GM script.  The link is in the [Delete Questions Archive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/deleted-questions-archive).

Comment: I've added a link to a cached copy of the script. Beware, it'll probably stop working at some point.

Comment: it did stop working

Answer (score 1):

> If the dropdown had a notification, that something happened, and only showed what happened since the last time, that would be great.

Your user page has this on the tabs, with numeric indicators; look closer. Click through and changes are highlighted.

(and you have direct links to those tabs on the drop-down.)

Comment: The numeric indicators are good, but they don't allow you to 'tell at a glance that "something" has happened': You have to go to your user page first. OK, you can consider this as minor. For me, the **major loss** of functionality would be if there's no replacement of the "favorites" tab of the `/recent` page.