# Notifications from favourite questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

Wouldn't it better if we get notifications from the questions which we favourite? It would help, by getting us notified about new answers to our favourite questions.

Or,

Is this feature already existing?

Comment: We get notified about the the activity of our favorite questions. It is showed in favorite tab of our profile.

Comment: I want notifications in the inbox, same as when it's my question.

Comment: This used to be the case, years ago. It's known as "The Envelope": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84109/can-we-please-get-an-option-for-the-envelope-feature-back.

Comment: I like this idea and have thought of it myself as well.