# Why was a slew of questions recently deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What topics can be discussed here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83253/what-topics-can-be-discussed-here)

I recently noticed quite a few recent "popular" questions were deleted. My question is why? [1](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1QxTwueCBEcJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/82692/why-cant-you-roll-out-new-features-the-way-everybody-else-does+site:meta.stackoverflow.com/questions+why+cant+you+roll+out+new+features+the+way+everybody+else+does&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com) [2](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OWjGefanjxMJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope+site:meta.stackoverflow.com/questions+eeeek+what+happened+to+my+envelope&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com)  (linked to google cache)

Why were these questions deleted? Were they in any way considered harmful to the community? I don't think so. I'm not sure if my questions will live long enough even to get an answer. But I don't have high enough reputation to see a close/delete reason or who by. For what purpose were these very popular questions deleted?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83253/what-topics-can-be-discussed-here/83332#83332

Comment: Clearly it was natural atrophy

Comment: Popular does not mean valid and correct for meta. See: "Favorite Programming Cartoon".

Comment: They were deleted in order to cause a flurry of why were they deleted questions, which too will be deleted, causing even more such questions.  We are trying to achieve criticality so that meta can supply power to all of stack exchange.

Comment: @Adam: If that was the intention, deleting those questions was indeed a great success. So please stop whining that it works. `:)`