# What's with the censorship here on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What topics can be discussed here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83253/what-topics-can-be-discussed-here)

I can understand that questions will be closed and/or edited here on meta and I'm fine with that. But recently there were two very active questions,

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82692/why-cant-you-roll-out-new-features-the-way-everybody-else-does

where Jeff's opinion wasn't popular and was downvoted heavily. They are now completely gone. (although still available in google's cache).

So, we can talk all we want here, but if the users are too unhappy then the thread disappears?

I understand that ultimately the SE team decides how the features will be, and that's fine, but why remove the discussion about it? The discussion wasn't particularly rude, it was just normal disagreement about how the site should work.

I'm guessing this question will be deleted as well, before you do, please take a moment to think about *why* you want to silence any disagreement. Do you honestly not think it's a bit... wrong?

Comment: Even my question about it was deleted, not closed - I simply don't understand the strategy here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83319/eeeek-what-happened-to-the-envelope-question

Comment: Have you seen [this question and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83253/what-topics-can-be-discussed-here)? I think the main thrust of your question is handled there. So, yes, prepare for deletion :)

Answer (score 1):

The first question was toxic to keep, as it overshadows actually important questions on upcoming changes (asked by Jeff, who woulda thunk!) such as the upcoming [adding of a reputation cap.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81929/should-we-cap-reputation-gained-from-questions-at-2000/81947#81947) It's not censorship; it's called "moving along."

The second question must have been deleted because the SE development process is not up to the community to discuss.

---

If you want to complain about "unfair deletion", how about [bug/feature requests posts that get deleted as a form of quickly marking status-completed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81095/when-users-page-need-to-scroll-please-arrage-sorting-from-left-to-right-then-t) :)