# How do we (now) close meta questions that are no longer relevant?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, per-site-meta

On per-site metas we sometimes need to close the following two types of questions:

- The question was related to a project or contest with a particular duration, and that time has passed.
- The question was about something that the community needed to decide, and a decision was made and implemented.

In both cases we want to close these questions to fend off new answers.  In the latter case, if a decision needs to be revisited we want a new question that takes the history into account, not new answers to a two-year-old question.

We [used to use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49466/162102) "too localized" for this (at least on the sites I frequent).  Now that "too localized" isn't available as a reason, what close reason should we use for such questions?  None of the default options seem appropriate -- it's not off-topic, not unclear, not too broad.  (I'm discounting "primarily opinion-based" as that's a lot of what's *valid* on metas, so it would be ironic to use it here.)

Comment: on meta.SO there is the offtopic -> cannot be reproduced.  Is that available on all metas?  If so, use that.

Comment: @Servy apparently not (just checked a couple different sites).

Comment: Couldn't mods set up custom close messages on their own metas?

Comment: In most cases I wouldn't worry about trying to keep up with relevance. For things like contests, it's usually pretty obvious that it's over from the posts themselves.

Comment: @MonicaCellio IMHO it's better to handle that via accepted answers and possibly status-completed tags. Especially when it's not immediately clear from the existing posts *what* the conclusion was. And once in a while it's beneficial to resurrect an old discussion in the same thread, though that's really rather situational.

Comment: It's a huge problem not having 'too localized'.  On SO I just had to use a custom flag, and put some 'Too Localized' text in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, I would think that encouraging a mod to add the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag and possibly lock the post, would serve the purpose.