# MSE should handle questions about a single SE site when they're asking for external input

Tags: discussion, off-topic

A [fairly old question about how we do things on Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217325/how-should-ask-ubuntu-handle-old-questions-and-answers) just got closed with the site-specific off-topic close reason that you have on MSE:

> This question's topic is **only** applicable to one specific site in the Stack Exchange Network. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should relate to features or policies that commonly apply to the network or the software that drives it, within the guidelines defined in the help center. You should ask this question on the meta site where your concern originated.

You've almost certainly been through a process to arrive at that message, but as I've just commented, I think its current incantation encourages something that is really counter productive.

When I asked that question, **I wanted external input, fresh eyes, novel thought, different experiences to contribute a solution to a problem that we've been fighting about internally for years**. I got some of that and I'm thankful for it.

But this close reason essentially says "Go away. Deal with it on your own."

That isn't helpful. I feel quite strongly that MSE is *the* venue for stuff like this. And while I can see why you might want to keep drama from other sites spilling over, MSE should be available for sharing ideas and helping a site make itself better.

This message needs tuning.

Comment: I think you (and Ask Ubuntu) discussed the [issue that you complain was closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217325/282094) on your Meta here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6994/can-we-have-more-than-3-custom-close-reasons-pretty-please and "network wide" the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/282094) cleans up the rest. If you need 'a flag for historic lock' then your own Meta is the place to discuss that, not here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217325/282094 -- that's why the other question here was OT. Edit and explain ***there*** why it should be reopened, !here.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that that question is asking how *Ask Ubuntu* should do something for which there are no hard network-wide rules, i.e. the communities are free to do what they want as long as it obeys common sense. That makes it a site-specific question in my book; it can only be definitively answered by a high-scoring answer on Ask Ubuntu Meta, which indicates *that community* approves of the policy stated in the answer.

Please consider rewording your question as e.g. "How could technology sites handle old questions and answers?" and remove the [askubuntu](/questions/tagged/askubuntu) tag; of course, it's fine to use specific examples from Ask Ubuntu.