# Why can't we re-vote on answers?

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, down-votes, edits

Earlier I answered a question, and somebody offered a completely different answer which (upon my understanding of the original question) was invalid. Because this answer wouldn't work, I down voted it.

However, the Original Poster then edited the question and offered some more information, at this revelation, my solution became invalid and the other answer became valid. I tried to then take my down-vote away (because I was admittedly wrong) but unfortunately, I was unable to do so. Now this user has suffered a reputation decline because I misunderstood the OP.

Why can't we remove down-votes?

Comment: I assume it's [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607402/php-delayed-database-request-also-without-live-page/3607446#3607446)? I just upvoted it for you.

Comment: @Martin: because of reputation differences, an upvote isn't really a true reversal of a downvote. @Daniel said that he only wanted to remove the downvote, not upvote the OP instead.

Comment: @AndyE - I thought a score of 0 wasn't really fair on that answer anyway and was quite happy voting it up in its own right.

Comment: you may want to support devinb's proposal [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58129/allow-votes-to-be-changed-at-any-time-but-warn-and-leave-a-note-in-the-revision).  @Martin: fair enough :)

Comment: @Martin Cheers mate :) I feel atoned haha

Answer (score 1):

You normally can remove down-votes after the post you downvoted has been edited. Each time it's edited, you can change the vote once if I understood it right.  I had the same problem, but I could retract the down-vote after the answer was edited.

So just check once in a while, or maybe ask the poster to edit his answer so you can remove the downvote?

Comment: I know but it's a roundabout way of doing it. I was trying to do the honourable thing of admitting I was wrong, but I couldn't

Comment: sometimes you have to swallow your pride and eat the dirt at the shoes of your opponents. If you chew it well enough, you can always spit it back in their faces later on. ;-)