# Unvote (toggle vote up)

Tags: support, voting

Is there a way to undo when voting up (or down)?

If not, it would be useful.

Comment: Clicking the arrow again does not work?

Comment: @Bobby, Does not work for comments.

Comment: @jia3ep but comments are not having downvote.

Comment: @Himadri, comments are have an upvote, and it is impossible to undo it.

Comment: @aparente001 that is not a discussion. It's a pure support question, and maybe a feature request in case the feature doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - So how do I make a feature request?

Comment: @aparente001 by tagging as [tag:feature-request], but in this case it's not a feature request since the feature already exists. (And existed when the question was originally asked)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - The feature exists?  I thought the answer was that after five minutes you can't change the accidental vote.

Comment: @aparente001 question here does not mention time, so yes such feature exists. There were numerous requests since then to remove the limit and let us undo without any limits, which are indeed feature requests. (As they ask to change behavior of an existing feature)

Comment: I don't remember why I closed this as duplicate, but I was wrong as the question here is not about limits, just how to do that. Reopening.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try clicking the vote button again. You've got [5 minutes to change your mind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046), after that you can't change your vote, unless the entry has been edited.

Comment: Grace period is the same as the editing window, 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, grace period was throwing me off.

Comment: Looks like going Back in the browser, or refreshing, might also nullify the grace period: I accidentally upvoted the wrong comment and refreshed, and could not undo it, despite the (presumed) 5 minute window not having closed.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I upvoted every comment here and cannot IMMEDIATELY unvote, even though the cursesr changes to an action one. System info: Chromium on Ubuntu 32bit.

Comment: Grace period doesn't make sense to me. I came back to an item 18 HOURS later, after realizing that what was presented as a solution was only valid for a narrow problem set. So, useless to me. But there's my up vote, cast in stone.  Also: "up again" as undo, is UI-design broken.

Comment: @fortboise, the vote lock is [the result of some gaming the system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046).

Comment: Thank you for explaining, and the link. I see in the comments of that thread that no one other than the implementers thought it was a good idea either. Gaming patterns should be detected and fixed without breaking the core functionality, which is providing for an accurate tally of endorsements. If status is so valuable that people are willing to game the system, maybe status needs to be downvoted.

Comment: I agree the locking it in is a bad idea. But my main comment on the other thread,

Comment: I do not understand the system which does not allow me to revoke my upvote, but allows to change my upvote to downvote! I do not want to downvote, I just want to revoke my upvote. - it just turned out that the answer which seemed to be a solution didn't prove to be one, but it took one day to figure it out.

Comment: @Paul you got it wrong. After 5 minutes, and until an edit is made, you can't change your vote, meaning neither just undoing it nor reverse it to the other type of vote

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wrote this some years ago. Today I know how this unlogical UI works. Expected: click down arrow to revoke upvote, click again to downvote. In reality: click upvote again to revoke it. After 5 minutes no vote change could be made.

Comment: @Paul sounds logical go me but guess each and his own view.