# Ninja edited questions need to let me undo my downvote

Tags: feature-request, edits, grace-period

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot retract downvote if post has been edited within first 5 minutes of posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62219/cannot-retract-downvote-if-post-has-been-edited-within-first-5-minutes-of-postin)

The OP posted the question [redirect with www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908278/redirect-with-www) with a line of text:

> plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me
>   plz help me

It was almost exactly like that. I felt the need to downovte. He ninja-edited, and I don't have a problem anymore... except, I can't undo the vote.

*ninja edit*

1. When one edits a question close to the posting time such that the revisions are not logged or shown, and the post appears as if it is original. The work of a ninja, assasinating previous content in total darkness.

Comment: It's also known as the "grace-period", I've added that tag.

Comment: It's called the "grace period" after the notorious ninja master known only as "Grace Note".

Comment: I thought Grace Note was known more for getting things perfect the first time, @mmyers; kinda the opposite of a ninja.

Comment: @PopularDemand: How can we mortals tell the difference? After five minutes and a little bit of swordplay, there are no witnesses to say.

Comment: @mmyers: Why, by being at the scene of the non-crime, of course. I've non-seen it a couple times.

Comment: You can wait five minutes (the grace period) before downvoting, this will ensure whatever was in the post would get logged. :)

Comment: I think we should raise him upon high for editing.

Answer (score 11):

**I don't think we need extra functionality for this.**

If someone is in such haste to just get ANYTHING posted up, no matter the quality, then they risk a downvote.

It's unlikely that you will downvote a question like that because of a minor spelling or formatting error.

If you feel the need to remove your downvote, edit the question  yourself.  Personally I think it should stand since they DID put `plzplzplzplzzplzplzplzplzplz` in the question initially, which was totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait till you get the reputation to edit the post -- then edit the post so you can change the vote.

Comment: I already can edit, but that's using the system a way it wasn't meant to be designed.

Comment: I don't really think that this behavior should be encouraged. See [Should we allow edits to reverse upvotes and downvotes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109859/should-we-allow-edits-to-reverse-upvotes-and-downvotes).

Comment: @Chris : Interesting, _all_ the answers to that question say the practice if fine.  If one is trusted enough to edit all posts they should be trusted enough to reverse a vote.

Comment: @Hogan Well, to be fair, Pekka is a bit equivocal on the issue: "[I use this 'feature' without shame and will continue to do as long as it's possible, **but it doesn't feel entirely *right*.** 'My vote should be locked until someone else edits the post' definitely sounds *more* right.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109859/should-we-allow-edits-to-reverse-upvotes-and-downvotes/109860#109860)"

Comment: @Chris : He certainly seems to be advocating using it while someone can.  Since people who can change the way it works have read that question and still it works the same way I believe it is safe to say they have given their tacit approval.

Comment: @Hogan Things don't always work that quickly around here. I've seen features that took a year to implement. I'm not going to second-guess "the management" until a moderator places one of the status tags on my question ([meta-tag:status-bydesign], for example).

Comment: @Chris : Good point.