# Change the hover-text on vote buttons not to say "click to undo" when it's not going to work

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, locked-votes

<del>I'm still getting flack about [this downvote I made](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4868910/733077).</del>
I downvoted an answer and added a comment explaining my reason. I was later convinced by other comments that it was not a good reason for downvoting. Upon attempting to retract my vote, I inadvertently locked it in.

The hover-text still (over a year later) says I can "click again to undo". But it's a big fat lie.

My specific problem has been resolved. But, I have stumbled across other questions where users have done this. In keeping with the push to help new users not to discover rules *after having broken them*, I think this text needs to be a little more aware, a little more accurate.

Comment: Aside: I've edited the answer, so you can remove your downvote now. It's downvote-worthy in my opinion, however. Just a link.

Comment: Thank you! I really have learned not to that. ... Whew. Conscience slightly clearer.

Comment: Not to do what? Downvote lazy answers that lambaste the asker for being lazy? Again, in my opinion, downvotes are justified.

Comment: But my reason was that the other answer was superior and I wanted to increase the spread. I didn't really have anything against the answer.

Comment: Oh. I suppose I could've edited it myself. :)

Comment: Well, true, that is not a great reason for a downvote. And yes, you could have edited it yourself: [Should we allow our edits to reverse our own upvotes and downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109859)

Comment: That answer lies in *not an answer* territory. I don't want to click another link in order to get that information... Especially since there's so much detailed information above, that answer provides absolutely *nothing* to the question overall. Downvotes are well deserved.

Comment: Apart from downvotes, wouldn't a flag as NAA be appropriate? Because it's just a link?

Comment: @J.Steen That is perhaps something I should have considered initially.

Comment: @animuson That was my original feeling exactly, but the timing of the answers makes the comparison a little unfair. I wouldn't want one of my own answers downvoted simply because a better one had come along.