# What if I want to reverse my vote?

Tags: support, voting

Few times I have decided to change my vote. The problem is that when originally answer is 0 and I vote up and after some though I want to reverse my vote, it goes to -1 vote.

Why not 0?

I don't want to vote for negative, just reverse my vote...

Comment: Hover over the voting arrows until the toolip comes up and note that it says "(click again to undo)"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't down vote, just click on the up-vote to undo the up-vote.

Note your vote will be locked [a few minutes after you vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046), so you can't change it unless the question has been edited since you voted.