# Recourse for Competitive Down-Voting

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes, tactical-downvoting, competing-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If you just witnessed tactical downvoting, is it a reportable offense?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense)

Recently miffed about an answer I gave that was technically identical to a competing answer, and although my answer was posted first, it was down-voted, the competing answer up-voted and accepted.

That said, the other answer was a better answer and deserved the up-vote/accept, but is it kosher to down-vote an answer simply because it's not the best response. Or is it common to have competing answerers down-vote your answer to receive better placement in the list of answers? If so, what sort of visibility and/or recourse does one have to justify their answer?

Comment: Also, first meta post, sorry if this Q isn't up to spec, just let me know if it doesn't fit the archetype.

Comment: How do you know your answer was downvoted by the answerer?

Comment: Which one of the 112 answers you've given are you referring to in this question? [Is it this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11322030/308661)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's just the way voting works. If your answer was a significantly bad way to go about it, though, it may have deserved the downvotes. You can always just ask politely for a comment on why the downvote, and what you can do to fix it. Fix it, and people may withdraw their downvote. If it was just someone trying to get higher up in the answer list... there's not much you can do. Sorry.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - not sure that this was even necessarily the case in this instance, but to that point, what kind of visibility is available?

Comment: @Insilico, yes, that's the one.

Comment: Didn't mean to be trolling for "counter-votes" but thanks to whomever did.

Answer (score 9):

It wasn't me, no orange arrow:

[image]

Not the OP either, he has no downvotes recorded.  Just a passer-by, it is nothing unusual.

Comment: Ha! The shadow on that arrow does not match the position of the sun in Madison, Wisconsin. It's clearly 'shopped!

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags: Don't need Photoshop for that. The old Windows Paint is sufficient.

Comment: Who needs Paint? `$(".vote-up-off").removeClass("vote-up-on");`