# Why are downvotes locked in so quickly?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

Yesterday I downvoted on an answer, and posted a comment explaining why I disagree with the answer.

The author of the answer replied to my comment, and his reply convinced me that the answer was reasonable. Now I would like to remove my downvote, but I can't because it's locked in. What is the sense in that?

Comment: It's intended to limit [tactical downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18046/194296)

Comment: Assuming you misunderstood that answer, the author should edit their answer to clarify *any* possible misunderstanding, and then you can change your vote. (Or you could edit yourself.)